# Custom hierarchy WordPress menu - show only child pages or current active page

Tags: wordpress, menu, children

I am trying to create custom code for complex WordPress menu.
Let's assume that i have menu wordpress menu structure like this - Granchild is last node, there is no more children nodes:

```
Parent1
 -Child1
  --Grandchild11
  --Grandchild12
 -Child2
  --Grandchild21
  --Grandchild22
Parent2
```

My task is to create something like this:
When user is on homepage, only Parent1 and Parent2 are displayed as menu list items.
When user clicks for ex. to Parent1 and enter that page he can see menu structure like this( static, as list item inline)-only children pages of clicked page, but also only first level items :

```
|---------Parent1---------|--------Parent2-----------|
   |---Child1---||---Child2---|-----ChildN----|
```

Then let's assume that user clicks on Child1 in newly created ribbon.
When that page load user must see next structure:

```
 |---------Parent1---------|--------Parent2-----------|
       |---Child1---||---Child2---|-----ChildN----|
           |---Grandchild11---||---Grandchild12---|
```

Now user can click on any Grandchild element from list, and when load that page,which has not own children, on that page needs to be displayed same menu structure as in graph above.

I tried to implement it via this code (do shortcode statement is in header after menu):

```
function wpb_list_child_pages() { 
global $post; 
if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )    
    {$childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0&depth=1' );}
else
    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0&depth=1' );
if ( $childpages ) {
    $string = '<ul class="menidva"><center>' . $childpages . '</center></ul><br>';
}

return $string;
}
```

but it is not working as required.
I kept wordpress menu just for everyone can see real structure in dropdown styling.

Here is a link to site to test :[LINK](http://development.leadwebtech.com)

Can anybody please help me with this ?

Comment: Have you tried using CSS? If you use :

    <body <?php body_class(); ?>>

The `body_class();` function adds lots of classes to the body tag that you can then use as CSS selectors, not sure if there is enough classes to achieve what you are looking for but it could help. 

I'm not really clear on what your trying to do here when you say "but it is not working as required"

Comment: Have you seen link i attached? It is not working as per specification i wrote and draw ...not showing 3rd level

Comment: Yes I saw the link but your function wasn't clear. Are you saying that on this page http://development.leadwebtech.com/photography/lenses/ the inline nav should have Lens2 | Lens 1

Comment: Exactly...but that will be in third row..on second row must be lenses and cameras..and first row stays also unchanged...got it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry just wanted to be clear as it's not a straight forward thing to solve. I've had to mangle your code a little so I could test it locally and I may not be achieving exactly what you want but the answer below should help you solve your problem as I believe the else if statements are more or less what you need.

```
<?php

function wpb_list_child_pages() { 
global $post;

$ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
$root_parent_page = end($ancestors);
    echo $root_parent_page;

if(is_page() && (count($ancestors) >= 2)){
    echo 'YOU ARE ON A GRAND CHILD PAGE';
    echo '<ul>';
       wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $root_parent_page . '&echo=1&depth=1' );
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '<ul>';
       wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=1&depth=1' );
    echo '</ul>';
}   
elseif ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ){
    echo 'YOU ARE ON A CHILD PAGE';
    echo '<ul>';
       wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=1&depth=1' );
    echo '</ul>';
}
else{
    echo 'YOU ARE ON A PARENT PAGE';
    echo '<ul class="menidva">';
       wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=1&depth=1' );
    echo '</ul>';
}


}   

wpb_list_child_pages();

?>
```

Comment: That's much better! Now check link of my website please. When you click on photography-works great- displays lenses and cameras. Then when i click lenses, it types lens 1 and lens 2, which is perfect, but it is not showing parent menu before it (cameras and lenses). When you click on lense1 for example to open grandchild, it is displaying like it needs to display. Can you please just check me that part of code please? Thank you so much for help!

Comment: This seems to be working fine now, did you mange to fix it yourself or am I not understanding you correctly?